# Meaning of "Buck ten, buck fifteen, tops"

Tags: meaning-in-context, slang, dialogue

These lines are from the movie *Mr and Mrs Smith*. What is the meaning of the phrase *buck ten, buck fifteen, tops*?

> You get a look at him?
>
> Little thing. Buck ten, buck fifteen, tops.
>
> Maybe he’s Filipino.

Comment: @Silenus: It's true there's an entry in [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=a%20buck) for that sense. But I didn't know this usage before now, and it's not in the full OED, so I really don't see why you'd think this is a "learner's" question. There's little point in teaching learners a usage which most native speakers would struggle to interpret.

Answer (score 9):

"Buck ten" means "One dollar and ten cents", or 110 cents. So it presumably means here 110 pounds, or about 50 kilos. Likewise "buck fifteen" means 115 pounds. So:

> He looks like he only weighs 110 pounds, or 115 pounds at most.

Comment: I find this extremely odd. I have never ever seen the use of a buck (a dollar) used for weight like that.

Comment: I live in upstate New York. I've heard it all my life.

Comment: @Lambie Obvious, but buck = dollar = 100 cents. Buck ten = 110 cents. Change cents to pounds. Not uncommon in the States.

Comment: @Lambie, in actuality it is not being used for weight, it is being used as a form of numeral. So TonyK is actually giving the inferred meaning.The speaker is actually saying: "Little thing, 110, 115 at most." What those numbers actually mean comes from the context. Curiously you also hear it in monetary discussions. "How much does this job pay per year? A buck twenty?" Curiously that actually means the annual salary is $120,000. And just to confuse things more, if you are asking about consulting rates you might hear "a buck twenty" which in this context means $120 per hour. Context is king.

Comment: But it is being used for weight. You are equating $1.10 to 110 pounds. How can you say it isn't? Since you agree that $1.10 equals 110 pounds? I have never heard it in my entire life. Not in magazines, not in books, not on TV, not in movies (until now) not by speakers. And by the way, I have spent a lot of time in upstate NY, in fact.... I suspect this is just what the screenwriter thought was clever.

Comment: @Lambie, I never heard it used like this before either. But it's pretty obvious what it means, even to a Brit like me who would say "eight stone" instead of "buck ten".

Comment: @TonyK Aha, now we're getting somewhere. I think these Hollywood scriptwriters are always looking for ways to avoid clichés and sometimes their former English teachers would frown on some of their "comeuppances" [joke]. It may be obvious to us English speakers but it, nevertheless, gives one pause...I would have gotten rid of it, personally.

Comment: I just spoke to a friend who tells me this buck business is used in BOXING. :)

Comment: @Lambie No, this is not just Hollywood scriptwriters avoiding clichés. The English-speaking world is a big place, plenty of room for slang that we haven't heard before. In this case I've heard it too, and it's very slangy, but it's not artificial. And though the meaning *comes* from the dollar/cents meaning, it's not literally measuring weight in money.